# How to copy one TXT File from Assets folder to SD / Internal Storage Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, copy

I am trying to Copy a TXT File in Assets over to the SD Card / Internal Storage.
All examples are in Java, is there anyway this can be done in C#?

Java Code:

```
    final static String TARGET_BASE_PATH = "/sdcard/appname/voices/";

private void copyFilesToSdCard() {
    copyFileOrDir(""); // copy all files in assets folder in my project
}

private void copyFileOrDir(String path) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    String assets[] = null;
    try {
        Log.i("tag", "copyFileOrDir() "+path);
        assets = assetManager.list(path);
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            copyFile(path);
        } else {
            String fullPath =  TARGET_BASE_PATH + path;
            Log.i("tag", "path="+fullPath);
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists() && !path.startsWith("images") && !path.startsWith("sounds") && !path.startsWith("webkit"))
                if (!dir.mkdirs())
                    Log.i("tag", "could not create dir "+fullPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; ++i) {
                String p;
                if (path.equals(""))
                    p = "";
                else 
                    p = path + "/";

                if (!path.startsWith("images") && !path.startsWith("sounds") && !path.startsWith("webkit"))
                    copyFileOrDir( p + assets[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("tag", "I/O Exception", ex);
    }
}

private void copyFile(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String newFileName = null;
    try {
        Log.i("tag", "copyFile() "+filename);
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        if (filename.endsWith(".jpg")) // extension was added to avoid compression on APK file
            newFileName = TARGET_BASE_PATH + filename.substring(0, filename.length()-4);
        else
            newFileName = TARGET_BASE_PATH + filename;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Exception in copyFile() of "+newFileName);
        Log.e("tag", "Exception in copyFile() "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

How would the above code be done in C#?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution could look like my method to copy a database from the Assets folder to the device:

```
    public static async Task CopyDatabaseAsync(Activity activity)
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "YOUR_DATABASENAME");

        if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dbAssetStream = activity.Assets.Open("YOUR_DATABASENAME"))
                using (var dbFileStream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int b = buffer.Length;
                    int length;

                    while ((length = await dbAssetStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, b)) > 0)
                    {
                        await dbFileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    dbFileStream.Flush();
                    dbFileStream.Close();
                    dbAssetStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exceptions
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call it in `OnCreate` with `ContinueWith`

```
CopyDatabaseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
     if (t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
         return;

     //your code here
});
```

Comment: So I would just use my File Name instead of YOUR_DATABASE? Also where does this save to?

Comment: Yes, instead of YOUR_DATABASENAME you use your file name. This method can be saved anywhere inside your project. Call it where you want to copy the file.

Comment: Where exactly is `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` ? and can I add a Subfolder?

Comment: Please read the documentation about SpecialFolders. Yes it is possible to create subfolders.

Comment: How would I call this method on the OnCreate Method?

Comment: No need to close the streams as "using" keyword closes and dispose it automatically.

Comment: That 1024 value on buffer... Could I get a memory leak if I don't use a buffer and try to copy a big file with dbAssetStream.CopyTo(dbFileStream)? I'm working that way and without buffer (My DB size is 30MB) and it works fine